# Can't use column-count in media query

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code with `column-count` property and it doesn't work in the media query for some reason!

```
.masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .masonry {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    .masonry {
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="masonry">
            <div class="item">text</div>
            <div class="item">text</div>
            <div class="item">text</div>
            <div class="item">text</div>
            <div class="item">text</div>
</div>
```

So can anyone help me to figure out what's wrong with the code or what I'm doing wrong?

Actually, when I tested it the media query didn't show in the inspect on Chrome but when I tried to put another property like `color` it worked!

Comment: i dont think the problem lies in the media because i dont see the 3 colums un the first place. this is not the way you are supposed to use column-count i think

Answer (score 0):

simply get rid of

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Since column-count splits the div with its own height, and inline-block make all the divs on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.masonry {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .masonry {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    .masonry {
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
}
.item {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
            <div class="item">text</div>
            <div class="item">text</div>
            <div class="item">text</div>
            <div class="item">text</div>
            <div class="item">text</div>
</div>
```